# Laravel apply middleware "only", "except" options to Route groups

Tags: laravel

The only reason I want to apply middleware options to my routes and not the controllers themselves is because I would like to build route groups from the same routes PHP file like the following, and I would like to do something like so:

```php
Route::prefix('api')
     ->middleware('api')
     ->middleware('auth:api', ['only' => ['store', 'edit', 'delete']])
     ->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['index', 'show']])
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
Route::prefix('web')
    ->middleware('api')
    ->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['store', 'edit', 'delete']])
    ->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']])
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

However, obviously, the official documentation listed you can have multiple middlewares with this method in routes:

```php
route->middleware('middleware1', 'middleware2')
```

Is there anyway to apply the "only these methods" and "except these methods" to route groups? If no, is there another way to go around this problem within my controllers, so that they know which route group the request is from and use different middlewares accordingly?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're opposed to creating Route Groups and adding middleware to the controller methods separately, compared to passing an array of methods that will either have or not have the middleware? While I see what you're getting at, it seems like more of a feature request that should be submitted to the founder of Laravel, as to my understanding you can achieve what you want, just not the way you want.

Comment: @JoshuaMcNabb That question was from so long ago. Haha. I think basically I wanted a way to write code without duplicate, since I had a lot of controllers that basically need the same settings, and writing duplicate code in controllers isn't exactly "good programming practice". And perhaps the second reason was that I thought there was an official way to do so, since it seems like a wanted feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, [route groups](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-groups) (as suggested in the comments) are the "official" way to do what you're describing, particularly if you nest them.

> Nested groups attempt to intelligently "merge" attributes with their parent group. Middleware and where conditions are merged while names, namespaces, and prefixes are appended. Namespace delimiters and slashes in URI prefixes are automatically added where appropriate.

You can also supply an array of options to the `group` method:

```php
// routes/api.php
$namespaces = [
    'namespace1',
    'namespace2',
    'namespace3',
    ...
];

foreach ($namespaces as $namespace) {

    Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace], function() {

        Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'api',
            'middleware' => [
                'api',
                ['auth:api', ['only' => ['store', 'edit', 'delete']]],
                ['auth:api', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]]
            ],
        ], function() {

            // api controller methods here

        });

        Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'web',
            'middleware' => [
                'api',
                ['auth', ['only' => ['store', 'edit', 'delete']]],
                ['auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]]
            ],
        ], function() {

            // web controller methods here

        });

    });

}
```

Note however that you may need to rearrange the array order to get the desired effect:

> Middleware are executed in the order they are listed in the array